# Why is my "for()" not working

Tags: game-maker

```
for(xwingwaves = 0 ; xwingwaves < xwingwc ; xwingwaves += 1)
{
    if(alarm[3] = -1) alarm[3] = 500;
}
```

my for is getting activated but my if is not getting started. Coded in gamemaker. 
xwingwc = 2;

Comment: what does  error say ?

Comment: there is no error. It is just not starting. thats the point :/

Comment: should be `alarm[3] == -1`

Comment: But I think it is not related to your problem. did you define `xwingwaves`?

Comment: Isnt the for defining the xwingwaves?

Comment: Nope you have to define

Comment: xwingwc = 2; And in my other for i didn't had to define it first.

Comment: Are you sure alarm[3] is -1?

Comment: Can you log something inside loop?

Comment: the alarm[x] is counting down from a value to -1. If I make a game with 60FPS it is counting the alarms down with 60 per sec. If my alarm is 600 it takes 10 sec to reach 0. And then it goes to -1 because it finished

Comment: But `alarm[3]` can never change during the loop. This makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

`==` instead of `=`

```
if(alarm[3] == -1) alarm[3] = 500;
```

and `for(var xwingwaves = 0;` instead of `for(xwingwaves = 0;`

[GameMaker: Studio - Loops](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-Hyi4cU4-s)

Comment: Doesnt change anything.

Comment: @Pasgru `check for(int xwingwaves = 0;`

Comment: I did change nothing it still doesnt check the if()

Comment: I found another problem. If I make the if() without the for it also doesn't get checked?? It has to do something wiht the if()

Answer (score 1):

is there a `var xwingwaves` before the loop? I think you're just missing the declaration.

Comment: Isn't for() defining the var?

Comment: The `for(xwingwaves = 0 ; xwingwaves < xwingwc ; xwingwaves ++)` defines the value, but it doesn't declare it. You'd need to add a `var` before the name in the `for()` like in Khaled Alam's or imudin's answer, or declare `var xwingwaves` before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but you do strange thing.

```
for (xwingwaves = 0 ; xwingwaves < xwingwc ; xwingwaves += 1)
{
    if(alarm[3] = -1) alarm[3] = 500;
}
```

Here you start `alarm[3]`, if it isn't started.

1. Here you check `alarm[3]` multiple times. You do same thing 2 times. No reason to do this. No reason to use `for` loop. No any difference with simple:

   ```
   if (alarm[3] = -1) alarm[3] = 500;
   ```
2. Keep in mind that if you haven't any code inside `alarm[3]` event (empty event), it won't be started (in this case just add one line od code, like `// empty` inside)
3. And keep in mind that this code starts `alarm[3]` insde object, where this code placed (or called from, if the code placed in script).

Answer (score 0):

```
for(xwingwaves = 0 ; xwingwaves < xwingwc ; xwingwaves += 1)
{
    if(alarm[3] <= -1) alarm[3] = 500;
}
```

//also i dont understand why you loop this? heres the code you need

if(alarm[3] <= -1) alarm[3] = 500; //the loop is meaningless put it in step event